# How do you make objects move when the mouse touches them without click and drag matter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, matter.js

I have a ball that a user can interact with using matter.js. Currently, the ball can move while dragging it by clicking and moving the mouse. How do I make it so the user can interact with the ball by passing over it with the mouse without clicking?

```
let mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine);
World.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this reduce to basically detecting the mouseconstraint annd ball collision, then pinning the ball to the mouse position with [`setPosition`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_setPosition) per frame after that?